# wald-estimator tag: What is it?

Tags: discussion, tags

What is Wald estimator? the tag [wald-estimator](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/wald-estimator) has no wiki and unclear use, is it just a synonym for wald test, or something else? (some of the use should be retagged to [wald-test](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/wald-test).)

Comment: googling leads to [this](http://cameron.econ.ucdavis.edu/e240a/ch04iv.pdf) using *Wald estimator* in the context of instrumental variables. This meaning might be used in https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/322862/covariance-bernoulli-distribution-and-instrumental-variables.  Also https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/219367/how-can-i-compute-the-standard-error-of-the-wald-estimator

Comment: Unless someone protests soon, I will start cleaning up this. First retagging to wald-test when appropriate (more than 50%). I don't think a synonym to wald-test is correct, since there are appropriate non-synonym uses of the name (but probably not enough to warrant a tag.)

Comment: The tag is now emptied.